# Is "Send to Onenote" tool included in Windows 10? If not, can i get it for free?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently and I no longer have the Send to Onenote tool which I loved using for making screen clippings.

After doing some searches it is not clear to me if it is indeed excluded from the Windows 10 version of OneNote. Is it, or is it just me?

If this is the case, is there a way to install just the "Send to Onenote" tool?

Comment: Yes;  Just install OneNote on the machine.  The shortcut also changed with the release of Windows 8.1

Comment: OneNote is already installed. It came with Windows 10 for me.

Comment: Universal Windows Application version of OneNote has different functionality then the desktop version. Verify `OneNote 2016` is installed

Comment: It just says OneNote v 17.6. I'm under the impression that I need to find a different version of OneNote... would this be free? My primary concern is to get the Send to OneNote tool.

Comment: OneNote is free, yes, have you installed the desktop version before asking these follow up questions?

Comment: I have now. I didn't understand there was a difference between "desktop" versions and a windows app. In any case, this worked perfectly! I got tripped up as well because when I went to the OneNote website, I had to select "other download options" in small print at the bottom since it said I already had OneNote installed.

Comment: Yes; I know; I have a SP3

Answer (score 0):

Screen Clipping was never my thing to use the keyboard shortcut to access.  Since you use the mouse to select and clip, it isn't efficient to go from mouse to keyboard and back to mouse.  Anyway, in 2013, you could hold the Windows key + S to execute Screen Clipping.  In 2016...nope.

Not to fear, the keyboard shortcut is still there, it is just different.  Now, you press Windows key + Shift + S to execute the Screen Clipping function.